# Is box-sizing available to use in email templates

Tags: css, email

I'm creating email templates and I've found this [CSS support guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) but `box-sizing` is not on there. I'm wondering if that CSS property is even supported, and if it is, which email client(s) support it.

Comment: That link hasn't been updated since 2014 and should not be considered a source of truth for HTML Email CSS support. Gmail now supports box-sizing as mentioned below - that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @sinisterOrange true - updated answer...from 2 yrs ago. =)

Comment: Campaign Monitor has updated their guide as of last month! https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/box-sizing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`box-sizing` is now [supported by Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css) which vastly increases the audience it applies to.

Answer (score 11):

No it's not supported. A simple google search will tell you:

Yahoo mail supports it according to:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3107/css3-support-in-email-clients/

[image: Box sizing support]

for many other css properties you can use following tables/resources as a reference:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

(i have no affiliation with campaignmonitor, i just keep above urls for reference)

Comment: Appreciate it - I had the 2nd URL, but not the css3 link.

Comment: Annoying that CM doesn't even mention it on its reference list (Rahul's second URL).

Answer (score 1):

Box-sizing is not supported by the most email clients. As far as i know only Yahoo Mail & Lotus Notes support it. So you probably should not use it.

Answer (score 1):

That need some **update from 2018/03**

box-sizing - is **supported by Gmail**, but not in all email clients.

For example **mail.yandex.com (mail.yandex.ru) still don't supported** it. I don't have full list of suppoting such style, but you surely can not rely on it even now.